# Postgres removing a set of text from a column but keep the remaining text

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am trying to find a way of bulk removing the word null from a particular column.

At present we have a column that has a set of numbers and then the word null afterwards.

```
043 null
00 null
1 null
1 null
1 null
1 null
10 null
10 null
103 null
11 null
11 null
1102/133 null
114 null
```

I am looking for a way of removing the word null from this column but keep the rest as is.

Whats the most efficient way of doing this? I am using postgresql 12.

Comment: Using `replace` or `regexp_replace` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
  customer
SET 
   address = REPLACE (
      address,
    'null',
    ' '

   )where address like '%null%';
```

This replaces the nulls in the column address with the value ' ' which is basically nothing.

This did the job for what I needed.

Comment: I would set the hole column to a (SQL) NULL: `set address = null where trim(address) = 'null'`